# parsing json with jquery

Tags: jquery, json

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

$.ajax({
method: "get",
url: 'ctr_seearmylist.php',
dataType: 'json',
data: 'get="squad"',
success: processSquads()
});

});

function processSquads(response)
{
alert(response);

}
```

Why isn't it working? How can I use the Json result that I'm getting?
The Json result looks like this[[1,2]][[1,2]]

This is how the php function that is called looks like:
    {......
    $temp[0]=$id;
    $temp[1]=$squad_id;

```
$result[]=$temp;
}
$result=json_encode($result);
return $result;
```

I looked at the response I get in firebug and I receive this: 
  **[["1","12"],["2","3"],["3","7"]]** but I can't manage to write it out. I would want to write out just 1, 2, 3, but I can't even write it as it is.

I should mention that I tried to parse it using jQuery.parseJSON, but in the function process squad doesn't even get send the parameter. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe functions should be declared BEFORE they are used? ;)

Comment: @shybovycha; it is declared before it's used, the call is when body has loaded (call back), the function is declared immediately.

Comment: @shybovycha: Declaring a function with the "function identifier(...){}"-syntax actually declares it in the beginning of its scope, so even if it wasn't used as a callback as roe pointed out, it would still work. Read about "hoisting" if you're curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
success: processSquads()
```

This line actually calls 'processSquads', I think you want jQuery to call it when it's done...

```
success: processSquads
```

HTH.

Comment: Thank you, now the function can see the parameter, but I still have a problem selecting only some things from it. I tried iterating through it in a for and addressing it by response.items[i] but it's not working

Answer (score 2):

Leave the parenthesis way from the callback definition:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "get",
    url: 'ctr_seearmylist.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'get="squad"',
    success: processSquads
});
```

If you want control over what is exactly passed into your callback method, you can wrap the definition into an anonymous function — e.g.:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "get",
    url: 'ctr_seearmylist.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'get="squad"',
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
         processSquads(data, XMLHttpRequest);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery documentation states that:

```
success(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)
```

A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the 'dataType' parameter; a string describing the status; and the XMLHttpRequest object (available as of jQuery 1.4). This is an Ajax Event.

So, you have to make sure arguments are right.